# Examine HTML output when debugging MVC Views

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

Is there a way to view what HTML has already been produced by an MVC Razor View when stepping through it with a debugger?

For example, in a view such as the following:

```
...
@Html.Raw(someString)
@Html.Partial("_SomeCommonComponent")    
@Html.Raw(someOtherString)  <---------- Execution broken at breakpoint here
...
```

Is it possible to see the combined output of just the first call to 'Raw' and the Partial view?

The reason I ask is that I have several complex calls together, (some which produce no output at all) and one of them is inserting incorrect characters, and I'd like to be able to find which call is the culprit by stepping over the code until the incorrect character has been output.

Comment: I recommend moving the logic to the model in order to simplify the view interaction with the model. Much easier to debug as well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Visual Studio you could put a break point on a code line in the view, then add a watch on both the Html.Raw(somestring) and Html.Partial("_SomeCommonComponent") method calls. You should then be able to see the HTML values in the watch window.

Also try and watch the [ViewContext.Writer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.viewcontext.writer%28v=vs.118%29.aspx) property in the view.

Comment: Thank you for that idea! It works well for methods that return MvcHtmlStrings like 'Raw' and 'Partial'. Some methods don't seem to return values (e.g. Html.EndForm()) and just write directly. It would be nice to be able to capture their output as you go along as well.

Comment: I've just had a quick look at the this.ViewContext.Writer property in the view. Add a watch to it and you might be able to see output going along.

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.viewcontext.writer%28v=vs.118%29.aspx

Comment: You got it! ViewContext.Writer.ToString() is exactly what I was after.